# load bearing stair components

Tags: stairs, load-bearing, storage, timber-framing

I've just opened up the under stair area with a plan to convert into storage.
Can anyone tell me what parts A and E are doing in the following [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFwiQ.jpg)? They don't appear to be load bearing to me.

I want to remove A so I can fit a door between B and C.

[image: all parts]

[image: A close up]
Doesn't look to be doing much... maybe stop the stringers from splaying in/out?

[image: E top]
I can't see how this is doing much either...

Comment: Stopping the stringers from splaying out seems like a pretty important role to play, though the treads and risers will do a pretty decent job of that.

Comment: BCD are for attaching drywall ... E is the same (with few additional 2x4) ... A is for attaching drywall with a possibility of a door or access panel

Comment: In a two-stringer stair I wouldn't be surprised if the intermediate studs prevent a lot of bounce. No, they're probably not completely necessary, but they may help make the stairs feel more solid.

Comment: @jsotola that makes total sense now you've said it, thanks. I think I'll be replicating B,C on the back wall anyway, to put insulation and plywood backing on, so if A is doing anything to take out any bounce as isherwood says they should help.

Comment: @jsotola make an answer out of that so it can be accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of those components appear to be load bearing.

I think that the following are the possible reasons for their existence.

BCD are for attaching drywall.

E is the same (with few additional 2x4).

A is for attaching drywall with a possibility of a door or access panel.